# Can a lambda return a response and wait for a new body without closing the session?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running a puppeteer function in AWS Lambda and I have a scenario that the user makes a POST request to the lambda with his username and email. The function is going to check if they are valid in a website and return the JSON to the user with the answer. Is it possible to use the same lambda session to receive another input/body from the user?

The reason I need it to be the same session is because each time an user and email is sent to the lambda, the puppeteer website is going to generate unique ID's that need to be used AFTER the user sends his data in that exact moment because it is logged into the website with an unique session.

I'm currently running this function in a NodeJS and it is fine because the session isnt going to be closed but the session is closed once the lambda returns the first response.

Comment: Lambda is meant to be stateless compute. Bests to store your unique id off somewhere (like dynamo), return it to the user, have the user include it in the next request then perform a lookup.

Comment: No, not possible. You need a stateless solution if using Lambda. Typically you would provide some state to the client in the response that can then be returned on the next request. JWT being the ultimate incarnation of this state.

Comment: thanks @Kisaragi .. since you replied first,
feel free to post your answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like people mentioned above, Lambda function is stateless resource and you can ultimately use dynamoDB to store any values such session ID or so.

Additionally, if the Lambda function should wait for response or any updated values by querying DynamoDB, then you can implement AWS [Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) or [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/) which provides the "wait" state.

See what States you can leverage in the AWS [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-states.html).